# Android - export single key/alias from keystore

Tags: android, android-keystore

I have a single keystore (JKS) with a lot of key entries / aliases for different apps in it.
Now one app will be moved to another developer and I want to export / extract the single key / alias for him.

```
> keytool.exe -list -keystore Keystorefile

Keystore-type: JKS
Keystore-provider: SUN

Keystore contains 6 entries

Appname1, 01.07.20XX, PrivateKeyEntry,
certificate-Fingerprint (SHA1): AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF:GG:HH:II:JJ:KK:LL:MM:NN:OO:PP:Q
Q:RR:SS:TT
Appname2, 29.05.20XX, PrivateKeyEntry,
certificate-Fingerprint (SHA1): AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF:GG:HH:II:JJ:KK:LL:MM:NN:OO:PP:Q
Q:RR:SS:TT
Appname3, 30.09.20XX, PrivateKeyEntry,
certificate-Fingerprint (SHA1): AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF:GG:HH:II:JJ:KK:LL:MM:NN:OO:PP:Q
Q:RR:SS:TT
Appname4, 18.02.20XX, PrivateKeyEntry,
certificate-Fingerprint (SHA1): AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF:GG:HH:II:JJ:KK:LL:MM:NN:OO:PP:Q
Q:RR:SS:TT
Appname5, 09.08.20XX, PrivateKeyEntry,
certificate-Fingerprint (SHA1): AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF:GG:HH:II:JJ:KK:LL:MM:NN:OO:PP:Q
Q:RR:SS:TT
Appname6, 11.02.20XX, PrivateKeyEntry,
certificate-Fingerprint (SHA1): AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF:GG:HH:II:JJ:KK:LL:MM:NN:OO:PP:Q
Q:RR:SS:TT
```

This is the output of my Keystore, now I want to export only the Key for `Appname2`. That this can be imported in another Keystore if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is bit less strigforward than exporting certificates (which can be exported with `-exportcert`) as you need to use `-importkeystore` and create new keystore with the key you want to "export", i.e.

> keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.jks -destkeystore
>   keystore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -srcalias ALIAS -deststorepass PASS
>   -destkeypass PASS

Alternatively you can just copy your current keystore file and then remove all keys from it but the one you want to export.

You can also check [Keystore Explorer](http://www.keystore-explorer.org/index.html) tool

Comment: What about using Android Studio?

Comment: That keystore explorer tool is perfect.  It really trivialises this sort of thing.